# EF6 MVC: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to make a simple foreign key connection in EF6 using a MVC application.  Basically, I have 3 tables.  Artwork, Artists, Art Type.  An artwork can have an artist and an art type.  An Artist can have multiple Artworks, an ArtType can have multiple Artworks.

Here is my artwork model class

```
namespace cmackay3_MVC_Arthouse.Models
{
public class Artwork
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
    [StringLength(255,MinimumLength = 20, 
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name up to 255 caharacters")]
    [DisplayName("Name or Title")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, 
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("Date Started")]
    public DateTime Started { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date, 
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [DisplayName("Date Finished")]
    public DateTime Finished { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "Field is Required")]
    [StringLength(511, MinimumLength = 20,
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter between 20 and 511 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "Field is required")]
    [Range(1,999999,
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value between $1 and $999,999")]
    [DisplayName("Estimated Value")]
    public double Value { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "You must select an artist")]
    [DisplayName("Artist")]
    public int ArtistID { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "You must select an art type")]
    [DisplayName("Art Type")]
    public int TypeID { get; set;}

    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
```

As you can see I have two virtual objects to server as foreign keys at the bottom.  I was told that these are the navigational properties.

Here is my Artist model class

```
namespace cmackay3_MVC_Arthouse.Models
{
public class Artist
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [StringLength(50,
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name shorter than 50 characters")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
    [StringLength(30,
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a middle name fewer than 30 characters")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [StringLength(50,
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a last name shorter than 50 characters")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$",
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number")]
    public Int64 Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Consignment Rate")]
    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    [Range(10,70,
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value from 10 to 70")]
    public int Rate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Artwork> Artworks { get; set; }
}
```

}

As I understand the Artwork list at the bottom serves to hold the multiple pieces of artwork an artist has.

Here is the final model class, the ArtType

```
namespace cmackay3_MVC_Arthouse.Models
{
public class ArtType
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(
        ErrorMessage = "This field is Required")]
    [StringLength(25,
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value under 25")]

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Artwork> Artworks { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my ArtEntities Class

```
namespace cmackay3_MVC_Arthouse.DAL
{
public class ArtEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Artwork> Artworks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> ArtistItem { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArtType> ArtTypeItem { get; set; }
}
}
```

Now whenever I try to access one of the views I receive an Error, Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entitySet.

I'm pretty lost, not too sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: Here is my artwork controller file.

```
namespace cmackay3_MVC_Arthouse.Controllers
{
public class ArtworksController : Controller
{
    private ArtEntities db = new ArtEntities();

    // GET: Artworks
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Artworks.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Artworks/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Artwork artwork = db.Artworks.Find(id);
        if (artwork == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(artwork);
    }

    // GET: Artworks/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Artworks/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Started,Finished,Description,Value,ArtistID,TypeID")] Artwork artwork)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Artworks.Add(artwork);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(artwork);
    }

    // GET: Artworks/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Artwork artwork = db.Artworks.Find(id);
        if (artwork == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(artwork);
    }

    // POST: Artworks/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Started,Finished,Description,Value,ArtistID,TypeID")] Artwork artwork)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(artwork).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(artwork);
    }

    // GET: Artworks/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Artwork artwork = db.Artworks.Find(id);
        if (artwork == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(artwork);
    }

    // POST: Artworks/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Artwork artwork = db.Artworks.Find(id);
        db.Artworks.Remove(artwork);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post how you creating context and which query you executed? Thanks

Comment: I posted my controller file, is that what you needed?  When I get the error it highlights

        // GET: Artworks
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Artworks.ToList());
        }

Comment: Thanks, I saw. Did you implemented somewhere OnModelCreating() method? I cannot see in your entities.